# Learning Pine Script/Ichimoku Alert

Tags: pine-script

Hope you're having a nice weekend.

I'm new to Pine Script, and coding generally, but have been trying to teach myself the basics. To challenge myself I am trying to write an Ichimoku Cloud alert. The are four indicators in the Ichimoku trend following system. If all four are bullish or all four are bearish you should enter. The four indicators are:

The TK lines. On TV they are listed as the conversion line and the base line. If the conversion line is above the base line then the TK is bullish. If the conversion line is below the base line then the TK is bearish.

The senkou lines. These are the lines that create the clouds. On TV they are listed as Leading Span A and Leading Span B. If Leading Span A is above Leading Span B then senkou is bullish. If Leading Span A is below Leading Span B then senkou is bearish.

Price. If price is above a bullish senkou cloud (when Leading Span A is above Leading Span B), then Price is bullish. If price is below a bearish senkou cloud (when Leading Span A is below leading span B), then price is bearish.

Chikou Span. On TV it is listed as the Lagging Span. It is price, but 26 time increments behind current price. If it is above the senkou cloud located 26 time increments before current price, then chikou span is bullish. If it is below the senkou cloud located 26 time increments before current price, then chikou span is bearish.

Below is my attempt to write a code that meets these conditions. If you guys see any problems will you let me know? Problems could be failures or just ways to make the code more efficient.

Thanks!

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © NorthVulcan
//@version=5
indicator("Ichimoku Grand Slam Alert")

//Import Ichimoku
conversionPeriods = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Length")
basePeriods = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Length")
laggingSpan2Periods = input.int(52, minval=1, title="Leading Span B Length")
displacement = input.int(26, minval=1, title="Lagging Span")
donchian(len) => math.avg(ta.lowest(len), ta.highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = math.avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

//Check if TK is bullish or bearish
bullishTK = conversionLine > baseLine
bearishTK = baseLine > conversionLine

//Check if Senkou Cloud is bullish or bearish
bullishSenkou = leadLine1 > leadLine2
bearishSenkou = leadLine2 > leadLine1

//Check if price is above or below senkou
bullishOpen = bullishSenkou and open > leadLine1
bearishOpen = bearishSenkou and open < leadLine1

//Check if Chikou is above or below Senkou Cloud
laggingLeadLine1 = leadLine1[displacement]
laggingLeadLine2 = leadLine2[displacement]
laggingChikou = open[displacement]
bullishChikou = laggingChikou > laggingLeadLine1 and laggingChikou > laggingLeadLine2
bearishChikou = laggingChikou < laggingLeadLine1 and laggingChikou < laggingLeadLine2

bullishGrandSlam = bullishTK and bullishSenkou and bullishOpen and bullishChikou
bearishGrandSlam = bearishTK and bearishSenkou and bearishOpen and bearishChikou
alertcondition(bullishGrandSlam, "Bullish Grand Slam!", "Bullish Grand Slam!")
alertcondition(bearishGrandSlam, "Bearish Grand Slam!", "Bearish Grand Slam!")
```

I haven't gotten any results yet as the market isn't open.

Comment: what is the specific problem with your code? ... what errors do you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.